# MySql Replication fails in slave when events started running and inserting data into local schema

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, large-data

I have a master and slave DB in mysql. We have more than 1m orders per month, when we tried to pull the data using mysql views from master it slows down the application. So we had created a slave and we are dumping the data into `sales report table` by mysql events (event runs on every 5 minutes and inserts new record to reports schema) . Whenever this event runs, replication started to fail.

I had some basic check, Is that issue because of mysql event but No

Is there any other better methods available to do this

```
 Master  
    Order Schema
      - order
      - xxxx
      - yyyy 

    Customer Schema
      - customer info

    Account Schema
      - customer account
      - xxxx
      - yyyy

 Slave
    <All the Master DB schema tables & schema we have it in slave by replication and we had created one more schema for reporting purpose>
    Order Schema
      - order
      - xxxx
      - yyyy 

    Customer Schema
      - customer info

    Account Schema
      - customer account
      - xxxx
      - yyyy

    Reports Schema
      - sales report
```